# Dropdown Selected Item Displaying Data From Database Into CheckboxList In A Panel

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net

I need some help regarding my project.
I have dropdown list and a checkboxlist in a panel. I want to display data from database into checkbox list after select the dropdownlist item.

```
This is the dropdownlist that will change the data in the panel based on the selected item

|---- Please Select -----|
|  Orange                |
|  Red                   |
|  Yellow                |
|________________________|


This panel with the checkbox next to the item that will be display from database after choosing the red from dropdownlist.
 __________________________
|                          |
|      [] Apple            |
|      [] Strawberry       |
|      [] Dragonfruit      |
|__________________________|
```

I do not know how to display the data in the panel after choose one item from the dropdownlist. This is some of my code that I already done.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label2 no-padding-right" for="form-field-1"><span style="color: red">*</span>Colour </label>                                                                                      
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlColour" runat="server" Width="330px" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlColour_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
    </div> 
</div>
<div class="form-group">   
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label2 no-padding-right" for="form-field-1"><span style="color: red">*</span>Fruits </label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanelSkill" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
               <asp:Panel ID="pnlFruits" runat="server" ScrollBars="Vertical" Width="400px" Height="150px" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderColor="Black" BorderWidth="1px">
                  <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkFruits" class="list-group-item" AutoPostBack ="true" runat="server" Width="95%">
                  </asp:CheckBoxList>
               </asp:Panel>  
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>                                 
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnAddFruits" Text="Add" />
        <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="lblFruits"></asp:Literal>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```vb
Public Sub GetFruits(ByVal sender As Object)
    attPage.SQLQuery = DC.Data_SupermarketItems("111", ddlColour.SelectedItem.Value)
    DS = DA.GetSQLDataset(attPage.SQLQuery)
    If DS IsNot Nothing AndAlso DS.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0 Then
        Dim row As DataRow
        For Each row In DS.Tables(0).Rows
            Dim Name As String
            Dim ID As Integer
            Name = row("FruitsName").ToString
            ID = row("FruitID")
            chkFruits.Items.Add(New ListItem(Name, ID.ToString))
        Next
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub ddlColour_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles ddlColour.SelectedIndexChanged
    If ddlColour.SelectedIndex > 0 Then
        GetFruits(ddlColour.SelectedItem.Value)
    End If
End Sub
```

The code that is done by me does not displayling the list of fruits after select the colour from the dropdown list. Can anyone help me ?